# Ionic app with payment integration through the Play Store

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, google-play

I have a mobile Android app developed with Ionic and would like to integrate the credit card payment that is set up in the Play Store to purchase apps.

I want to make Premium available to my users and to enable this mode it should make a payment through the app with the Play Store.

**He can choose between a monthly or yearly payment.**

You looked through the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native) and could not find anything that communicated with the Play Store data and that you could process payments through the Play Store.

I could implement a payment API such as Stripe, but I want to make payments from within my application through the credit card data set up in the Play Store.

I've seen it in some apps, and that way is used to remove ads.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your best bet is to follow the InApp purchase way.

Try the following plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2 with a q

And an article that may help: https://medium.com/@andrew.thielcole/in-app-purchases-with-ionic-3-af13b21f49f2